# Javascript app that needs to log in to external website and retrieve data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, mobile, authentication

So I am fairly new to javascript, but I am working on a mobile js app....

Is it possible to use jquery (ajax or json) to make my app log in to a remote website and retrieve data? I do not have back-end access to the remote site, only user credentials.

An example would be this site: https://crew.urbancrewltd.com/Account/Login

The external site is simply a page with a username & password form, and a submit (login) button. I would like the script to gain access to the site, using my username and password, and then...on the page that loads after login, retrieve some data.

For example:

```
$.ajax({

type: "POST",

url: "https://crew.urbancrewltd.com/Account/Login",

data: "username: Smith, password: 1234",

contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

success: callbackfunction,

 });
```

I am not looking for coding help here, I would simply like to know if the concept is viable, technologically speaking, given the limitation that I don't have back-end access. If so, I will try to learn the coding bit myself. I just don't want to waste days and weeks working on something that is impossible.

Thanks :)

Comment: Javascript can mimic user interactions to a certain point.  It still has some differences between user generated events and logical events that are treated differently, for security purposes.  Likewise, there are security measures over making requests to external sites that you may run into if those sites do not allow you to make ajax requests to them.  These are what people refer to as CORS(Cross Origin Resource Sharing) errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome developer tools to get the raw request when logging in, and see if you can reproduce the request using `curl` or `postman`.

Please note that you will need a backend (php, python, node, etc.) to circumvent the restrictions of modern browsers on CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing).